# FindAll - locating lines with a pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape a file for the following pattern:

```
Str[SPACE][MINUS]Str[SPACE]Number[SPACE][SPACE]Number[SPACE]Number
```

- Str can have spaces in it
- Str can have international characters ( so its not only a-z-A-Z  )
- Number can be positive or negative numbers

Examples of a Lines that matches (without "" )

```
 John Anderson - Hong Kong 24  486 2

 Fred Peters - Shanghai -4  186 0
```

I thought I had it right by doing this :

```
import re
text = open('pokertournament.txt') 
for line in text: 
    x = re.findall(r'.*(\s+[\-]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+[0-9\-]+\s+\s+[0-9\-]?).*', line)

    if len(x) != 0:
        print(line)
```

Where what I was trying was to search for a simplified pattern:

> [SPACE][MINUS][Str][SPACE]Number[SPACE]number[SPACE][SPACE]

But if I run this on a textfile with this content :

```
OLD - Break in, Allin win 1  Total Cards  Total Score Total Cards
John Anderson - Hong Kong 24  486 2
Fred Peters - Shanghai -4  186 0
OLD - Break in, Allin win 1  Total Cards  Total Score Total Cards
Peter Anderson - Tokyo Habor 24  486 2
```

Then result is that it finds this line only :

```
Fred Peters - Shanghai -4  186 0
```

How can I correct the expression so I might be able to understand how to use this correctly?

Comment: So you want to match the lines without `OLD`?

Comment: yes only the ones that fits the format, the full text file will have alot of other lines i also dont want - so only want the score lines in the above example 3 scorelines, John, Fred and Peter

Comment: Your regex is a bit off... `.*(\s+[-]+\s+[a-zA-Z\s]+\s+[0-9-]+\s+[0-9-]).*` should work. The main mistake you made was not including a space in `[a-zA-Z]`. You don't need to escape `-` in a character class if it comes before or after everything else too (eg.`[0-9-]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`(?m)^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+[- ]+[a-zA-Z\s]+\s[-\d\s]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/RQt1dI/2/)

`(?m)` designates multi-line matching.

In action:

```
s = """
OLD - Break in, Allin win 1  Total Cards  Total Score Total Cards
John Anderson - Hong Kong 24  486 2
Fred Peters - Shanghai -4  186 0
OLD - Break in, Allin win 1  Total Cards  Total Score Total Cards
Peter Anderson - Tokyo Habor 24  486 2
"""
import re
print(re.findall(r'(?m)^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+[- ]+[a-zA-Z\s]+\s[-\d\s]+$', s))
```

Output:

```
['John Anderson - Hong Kong 24  486 2', 'Fred Peters - Shanghai -4  186 0', 'Peter Anderson - Tokyo Habor 24  486 2\n']
```

Comment: youre amazing it works !! and awesome link for the regex101 !